# Prove that if $A\subset S^{n-1}$ with $\mu(A) = \frac12$, then $\mu(A_\epsilon) \ge 1 - e^{-n\epsilon^2/2}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convex-geometry

**Background**: On Pg. $44$ of [these notes](http://library.msri.org/books/Book31/files/ball.pdf), it is stated that:

> In the case of a sphere $\Omega = S^{n-1}$, we have the following pair of properties.
>
> 1. If $A\subset\Omega$ with $\mu(A) = \frac12$, then $\mu(A_\epsilon) \ge 1 - e^{-n\epsilon^2/2}$.
> 2. If $f:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is $1$-Lipschitz there is a number $M$ for which $$\mu(|f-M| > \epsilon) \le 2e^{-n\epsilon^2/2}$$
>
> We have seen how the second can be deduced from the first. The reverse implication also holds (apart from the precise constants involved). To see why, apply the second property to the function given by $f(x) = d(x,A)$.

**Theme of this post:** I need help deducing $(1)$ from $(2)$.

---

**Notation:**

- $S^{n-1}$ is the Euclidean sphere of unit radius in $\mathbb R^n$.
- $\mu$ refers to the *rotation invariant probability measure* on the sphere $S^{n-1}$. The measure of the entire sphere is $1$, that of a hemisphere is $\frac12$, etc.
- $d(x,A) = \inf\{\|x-y\|: y\in A\}$ where $A \subset\mathbb R^n$ is compact and $x \in \mathbb R^n$.
- A function $f: S^{n-1}\to\mathbb R$ is $1$-Lipschitz, if for any $x,y\in S^{n-1}$, $$\|f(x) - f(y)\| \le \|x-y\|$$
- $A_\epsilon$ is the $\epsilon$-thickening (or neighborhood) of $A$, that is $A_\epsilon = A + \epsilon B^n_2$ where $B^n_2 = \{x: \|x\| \le 1\}$.

---

**My thoughts:**
The author suggests to put $f(x) = d(x,A)$ in $(2)$. First we would have to check that this function is $1$-Lipschitz. Consider $x,y\in S^{n-1}$, i.e. $\|x\|=  \|y\| = 1$ and $A$, a compact subset of $S^{n-1}$.
Thanks to @OliverDiaz's comment, I now see that $$|d(x,A) - d(y,A)| \le \|x- y\|$$
Consider $a\in A$, then $d(x,A)\le \|x-a\| \le \|x-y\| + \|y-a\|$. So, $d(x,A) - \|x-y\|\le \|y-a\|$. Taking $\inf_{a\in A}$, we have $d(x,A) - d(y,A) \le \|x-y\|$. Interchanging $x$ and $y$, we get $d(y,A) - d(x,A) \le \|x-y\|$ and hence the required inequality.

Since $f = d(\cdot, A)$ is Lipschitz, there is some $M$ for which $$\mu(|d(\cdot, A)-M| > \epsilon) \le 2e^{-n\epsilon^2/2}$$ i.e. $$\mu(|d(\cdot, A)-M| \le  \epsilon) \ge 1 - 2e^{-n\epsilon^2/2}$$
It is easy to check that $A_\epsilon = \{x: d(x,A) \le \epsilon\}$. Due to the similarity in expression of what I have arrived at, and what I need to prove - I think I'm pretty close, but don't know what to do next.

Thank you!

Comment: I have clarified what $\mu$ is - it is not the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: So it is the normalized Lebesgue measure in the sphere. The only rotation invariant measures on the sphere are multiples of the Lebesgue measure on the sphere (aka uniform measure on the sphere). The book Pertti Mattila's *Geometry of sets and measures in Euclidean spaces: Fractals and rectifiability* may be a good place to look for these kinds of things.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! That book is on my reading list.

Comment: $|d(x,A)-d(y,A)|\leq d(x,y)$. For example, if $a\in A$, $d(x,A)\leq d(x,a)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,a)$ and so, $d(x,A)-d(x,y)\leq d(y,a)$ whence you obtain $d(x,A)-d(x,y)\leq d(y, A)$. Reverse the roles of $x$ and $y$ and violá!

Comment: Nice proof, that guarantees the function is Lipschitz!

Comment: I think to conclude, you may need to find the precise constant $M$ for $d_A:x\mapsto d(x,A)$, which according to your notes, $M$ is the value for which $\mu(d_A< M)\leq \frac12\leq\mu(d_A\leq M)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am continuing this answer from the thoughts you have added.

First of all, what is the median $M$ of the function $d(\cdot,A)$? We need to find $M$ that satisfies
$$ \mu(d(\cdot,A) \geq M) \geq \frac{1}{2}\text{ and }\mu(d(\cdot,A) \leq M) \geq \frac{1}{2}. $$
It is quite easy to see that $M=0$ satisfies this since $\mu(A)=\frac{1}{2}$.

As @OliverDiaz has mentioned in the comments, $d(\cdot,A)$ is $1$-Lipschitz. Now, observe that since $d(\cdot,A) \geq 0$, the part of bound $(2)$ that bounds $\mu(M-f>\epsilon)$ is useless (it measures $\{f<-\epsilon\}$, which is trivially $0$ for our choice of $f$).
So, using only the relevant part of bound $(2)$, namely the second equation on page 44 of the notes, we have
$$\mu(d(\cdot,A) > \epsilon) \leq e^{-n\epsilon^2/2}$$
and thus,
$$\mu(A_\epsilon) \geq 1 - e^{-n\epsilon^2/2}.$$

Comment: I agree that $M = 0$ works as the median of $f(x) = d(x,A)$, but could you explain why we care about the median here? For $(i) \implies (ii)$ I see how it is part of the solution. For $(ii) \implies (i)$, nowhere in the hypothesis have they mentioned that $M$ is the median. In fact, they only say that $M$ is *some number*. Please clarify, thanks!

Comment: My bad, I accidentally assumed that $M$ is the median. I also just saw the last two comments, which I missed earlier and seem to ask the exact same question. The author says "the reverse implication also holds _apart from the precise constants involved_", so it is possible that under solely the assumption that such an $M$ exists, we can only conclude that $\mu(A_\epsilon) \geq 1 - 2e^{-n\epsilon^2/2}$, which you have done.

Comment: Wait! On second thoughts, I accepted your answer because I think the median works. They started with a Lipschitz function on the sphere, and derived the bounds in (ii) by using the fact that $M$ is a median. Essentially, then, they are telling us that the bounds hold when $M$ is the median of $f$ (and the fact that the median exists is easy to prove, I'm skipping that in this discussion)! What do you think? I think the author's statement is weaker than what we have actually proved - we can precisely pinpoint the *number* $M$.

Comment: Precisely, but I thought your point was that the actual statement of $(2)$ does not say that $M$ is the median -- that is something we inferred separately (by going through the entire proof).

Comment: Yes, makes sense. One final clarification: if I am to edit the statement of (2) and specifically mention that $M$ is the median of $f$ (along with its existence, and the partial bounds obtained in the proof), then $(2) \implies (1)$ goes through as in your proof, correct? Perhaps the author should have been a little more specific.

Comment: Yes, it would work out then. To be fair, the author _did_ say that we might be off by a constant factor using the given statement.